# Dynamic update in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have to write a sql procedure that generate update. Procedure will have a parameter and in this parameter I will have names of tables. For example Customer1,Customer2,NewCustomer. All of tables will have field RecordId and I want to join this tables on this field.

In this case update will be like this

```
update t 
    set [Status] = 100
from 
   TemporaryTable t 
   left join Customer1 c1 on c1.RecordId = t.RecordId 
   left join Customer2 c2 on c2.RecordId = t.RecordId 
   left join NewCustomer c3 on c3.RecordId =t.RecordId

   where 
      c1.RecordId is null 
      and c2.RecordId is NULL
      and c3.RecordId is null
```

The problem is that numer of tables in the parameter will be optional. It could be 3 4 or 1  table and I have to join them with my temporary table to create update. The only thing I know is every table will have field RecordId on which I have to join this tables.

Comment: What did you do by now?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your query in a string and change it according to parameters

```
set @sql='
    update t 
        set [Status] = 100
    from 
       TemporaryTable t ';

    if(@Customer1 is not null)
        begin
        set @sql=@sql+'left join Customer1 c1 on c1.RecordId = t.RecordId';
        end
...other code
```

and in the end execute the string

```
print(@sql)
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

also, you can inject your own data in the middle of string,
hope it helps

Comment: Why inject the value of `@c1` and not parametrise the statement?